# What is $\Omega_{R/k}$, where $R = k[[x,y]]/(xy)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field, and $R := k[[x,y]]/(xy)$.

Is $\Omega_{R/k} \cong \frac{Rdx\oplus Rdy}{xdy+ydx}$ (as $R$-modules)?

This is certainly clear if $R = k[x,y]/(xy)$, but I'm not sure how to formally prove that this is true in this case.

Comment: No, that's not true. What you've written down is $\Omega^1_{\text{Spf}(R)/\text{Spec}(k)}$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis AHA! Awesome, that is actually what I want to be true. How do you formally see that it's $\Omega^1_{Spf(R)/Spec(k)}$? What's a good reference for this?

Comment: @AlexYoucis Also what's the difference between $\Omega^1$ of the Spf vs the Spec?

Comment: One is continuous derivations, and one is just normal derivations. Equivalently, recall that coherent sheaves on $\text{Spf}(R)$ are inverse systems of coherent sheaves on $\text{Spec}(R/I^n)$. The cotangent sheaf of $\text{Spf}(R)$ is just the system of cotangent sheaves on each of the $R/I^n$. So, it's $\varprojlim \Omega^1{\text{Spec}{R/I^n/k}$. I don't know a reference for this to be honest :(